# Remove Excel Add-In program installed by user from other windows account

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I developed an add-in for excel and the first version I send an email with the .exe file to users install (The system center was not working at that moment).

Now I need to uninstall the add-in (from system center). But the first installation has done in the user's account.

Is it possible for me to uninstall the first version of my add-in from other windows admin account (system center)? (e.g create a bat file that removes the windows registry entries) How?

Comment: There are some people marking this as off-topic.  It sounds like a question on how to programmatically uninstall, or request the uninstall of a previous version of an Excel add-in.  That being the case it could be on-topic.

Comment: @Orbling, it's about uninstalling it from a remote location ("system center", which sounds like a help desk or administration site), which makes it a network/system configuration issue and not a programming one, I think.

Comment: I want to uninstall an add-in (that is just a msi file), from a user account, but I want to run my .bat file(I think the creation of a bat file is the best option) from other account(the system center account, that is like an account on the same machine) on the same windows machine.

Comment: @fr33d0m: Thank you for the clarification, if the issue is how to run your batch file from another account, then that would be an issue for http://superuser.com/ probably.  There is a possibility it could belong here, if it strays in to programming methodology for solving that issue.  But probably not.

Comment: @Ken White: Well, from the update, you are on the right track.  My issue was only that there did not seem to be quite the clarity needed in order to get it closed/moved or answered.  Just a comment to make people aware before putting a close vote down to think on it, people can get a bit trigger happy. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours on Google I found that is not possible.

I can create a .bat file to uninstall the first version, but I can’t run on other account to uninstall. The users that installed need to run the .bat file to uninstall, because the first version had the option “just me” during installation by default.